# Calculating expected loss of posterior distribution

Tags: r, bayesian, posterior, numerical-integration

I'm working with 2 posterior distributions from AB tests. For the sake of simplicity let's assume:
$$ A\sim Beta(10, 20) $$
$$ B\sim Beta(5, 25) $$
I want to calculate the posterior expected loss of choosing B over A, with the typical squared error function $L(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = (\theta - \hat{\theta})^2$. I'm struggling finding a way to solve
$$E[L(\theta, \hat{\theta})] = \int L(\theta, \hat{\theta})p(\theta|X)d\theta = \int (\theta - \hat{\theta})^2p(\theta|X)d\theta$$
numerically in R? Any help is much appreciated.  Also not opposed to using the loss function $L(\theta, \hat{\theta}) = \mid{\theta-\hat{\theta}} \mid$.